# Webpack splitChunks how to get a chunk for each npm package (the chunk should include the dependencies for each package)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

I want to split my chunks with Webpack the following way:

Whenever I import an NPM package, like

```
import styled from "styled-components";
```

I want a chunk like:

```
styled-components.[contenthash:5].js  // INCLUDING ITS DEPENDENCIES
```

Here is the config I'm using:

**webpack.config.js**

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name(module) {
          const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
          return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And right now I'm getting every dependency of `styled-components` as a different chunk.
For example: the 3 packages below are all required by `styled-components`

[image]

Ideally, I would also like to have a `commons` or `shared` chunk to avoid possible modules there are required by more than one module.

Does anybody know how to to that?

Comment: I think you can pass a function for `chunks` for each `cacheGroup` you have created and then use path prefix to solve the problem.